# How to access a dictionary inside a struct

Tags: swift, dictionary, struct

I have a struct with a dictionary inside the struct and i would like to access the contents of the dictionary inside the struct.

This is my struct :

```
struct TransactionsObject: Codable {
    let UserInitiatedTransactions: [UserEdTransaction]?
    let UserReceivedTransactions: [UserEdTransaction]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case UserInitiatedTransactions = "UserInitiatedTransactions"
        case UserReceivedTransactions = "UserReceivedTransactions"
    }
}

struct UserEdTransaction: Codable {
    let transactionCode: Int?
    let transactionDate: String?
    let transactionType: String?
    let transactionTime: String?
    let transactionAmount: String?
    let transactionTo: String?
    let transactionFrom: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case transactionCode = "transactionCode"
        case transactionDate = "transactionDate"
        case transactionType = "transactionType"
        case transactionTime = "transactionTime"
        case transactionAmount = "transactionAmount"
        case transactionTo = "transactionTo"
        case transactionFrom = "transactionFrom"
    }
}
```

I would like to access this **transactionCode**. I have tried this to TransactionsObject.UserInitiatedTransactions.transactionCode and i get the following error :

```
Value of type '[UserEdTransaction]?' has no member 'transactionCode'
```

Comment: `UserInitiatedTransactions` is an array, so at least`TransactionsObject.UserInitiatedTransactions[0or1or2].transactionCode`

Comment: Unrelated, but there's no need for the `CodingKeys` enum is your property names match the JSON keys. The compiler can automatically synthetise the enum for you.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'BaraUserEdTransaction?' to expected argument type 'String!'

Comment: You don't have to preface every member's name with "transaction". The struct's name is `UserEdTransaction`. It's inferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the question should be *How to access an **array** inside a struct*

Second of all use `CodingKeys` only if the struct members and the keys don't match for example to *lowerCamelCase* variable names.

Third of all declare only the members of the structs as optional whose key equivalents could be missing

```
struct TransactionsObject: Codable {
    let userInitiatedTransactions: [UserEdTransaction]
    let userReceivedTransactions: [UserEdTransaction]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userInitiatedTransactions = "UserInitiatedTransactions"
        case userReceivedTransactions = "UserReceivedTransactions"
    }
}

struct UserEdTransaction: Codable { // no CodingKeys !!
    let transactionCode: Int
    let transactionDate: String
    let transactionType: String
    let transactionTime: String
    let transactionAmount: String
    let transactionTo: String
    let transactionFrom: String
}
```

---

The error occurs because `userInitiatedTransactions` is an array. You need an index subscription

```
print(transactionsObject.userInitiatedTransactions[0]) // can crash if the array is empty
```

or a repeat loop

```
for transaction in transactionsObject.userInitiatedTransactions {
    print(transaction.transactionCode)
}
```

Comment: What if i want to show this data inside a tableview cell

Comment: That's another question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a dictionary. `UserInitiatedTransactions` is an array. Arrays don't have `transactionCode`s, but an element of your array does.

Now the question becomes, which transaction's transaction code do you want?

If you want the first one, you can do this:

```
someTransactionsObject.UserInitiatedTransactions.first?.transactionCode
```

If you want the fourth one,

```
someTransactionsObject.UserInitiatedTransactions[3].transactionCode
```

If you want the nth one,

```
someTransactionsObject.UserInitiatedTransactions[n-1].transactionCode
```

Or you can get an array of transaction codes:

```
someTransactionsObject.UserInitiatedTransactions.map { $0.transactionCode }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the `array` as a `UserEdTransaction` object so you need to get an object from array then use like below:

```
TransactionsObject.UserInitiatedTransactions.first.transactionCode
```

**or**

```
TransactionsObject.UserInitiatedTransactions[0].transactionCode
```

**or**

```
TransactionsObject.UserInitiatedTransactions.forEach { (object) in
            print(object.transactionCode)
        }
```